# three.js edit-able text form control

Tags: three.js

Is there such a thing as an edit control (meaning a rectangle of text containing a caret and modify-able by user input) for `THREE.js`? If so, could somebody give me an example of its use? .  and, if not, must this functionality be simulated through DOM/JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such control class in `three.js`. You probably want to work with plain HTML textarea elements. If you want to apply a 2D or 3D transformation to a DOM element, consider to include one of the CSS renderers of `three.js` into your project:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS3DRenderer

Comment: I suppose the appearance and behaviour I'm describing is that of a `textarea`, but I want it to be located within a scene (as opposed to being within an HTML stream) and anchored to a particular 3D point.  Can this be done and, if so, how?

Comment: Try to use `CSS2DRenderer` for this use case and wrap the markup into an instance of `CSS2DObject `.

Comment: I assuming you're talking about something along the lines of the following (and apologies if I've bungled the markdown. but I'm still fairly new to Stack Overflow): ` const area = document.createElement( 'textarea' );
   const obj= new CSS2DObject(area);
   obj.position.set(x. y, z);
   scene.add(obj);` Will this work?
 `